# Browser não interpreta o javascript na sequencia certa

Tags: javascript, html5, navegador-de-internet

[image: o codigo Html]

[image: Aqui o codigo javascript]

o código javascript
[image: Como sai no Browser]

aqui no Browser lê o horario certo mas a img não sai a correspontende sendo quando eu coloco, na var hora um horario correspondente ao horario sai a foto certo mas quando deixo pro javascript manda para Browser sai a ultima leitura do javascript.

Comment: Posta o código e não a imagem do código que facilita o pessoal a te ajudar

Comment: Nesse seu código, `hora` vai ser uma string no formato `HH:MM`. Não adianta comparar essa string com valores numéricos como você está fazendo no seu código, por isso que está sempre caindo no `else`.

Comment: Otimos motivos para não usar imagens quando se pode usar texto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está comparando a variável "Hora", uma string, com um inteiro

```
if(hora > 0 && hora <=12) { ...}
```

isto vai sempre cair no else, por isto sempre vai cair na imagem da noite.

Faça:

```
var hora = date.getHours();
if( hora >= 0 and hora < 12 ) { 
sua imagem manhã 
} else if (hora < 18) { 
sua imagem da tarde 
} else { sua imagem da noite }
```

Com isto, sempre que vc utilizar a função "getHours()", ela vai te trazer a hora inteira, então basta comparar ela, porque 11: 01 e  11:59 vai ter retornar 11.

Comment: gostaria de trazer a hora com minutos ,não só a hora ,vou tentar fazer dessa forma usando o and

Comment: @EvertonCostaSouza, basta salvar em uma variável a hora com minutos para exibir na tela e esta variável só com a hora pra usar como teste pra imagem.

Comment: ,muito obrigado foi show ,tinha esquecido disso ,pois estou aprendendo react e lá não da alterar assim igual no javascript depois de declarada.

Comment: Acontece quando estamos mexendo com alguma linguagem e precisamos fazer algo em outra.  
Só aceita minha resposta, por favor, pra ajudar no perfil do Stackoverflow.   Abraço